# Alter matrix with command "find" and a mask

Tags: matlab, find

I am using a matrix and a mask. I tried it with magic(3) so my matrix is:

`8 1 6;3 5 7;4 9 2`. I also have a mask with `0 0 0;1 0 1;0 0 1`.
Now I do `find(mask==1)`. So I get the indices where mask == 1.
But from now on, I am stuck. I want to alter the matrix like this.
At all the indices of find(mask..) returned, I want to check if the value of my matrix has a certain value, if not, set it to 0.

Can you please help me?

Edit: let's say if the values of the matrix, where the mask is 1 are below 4, change them to zero. Result should be `[8 0 6; 0 5 7; 4 9 0]`;

Comment: Please add the desired output for this example.

Comment: and what do you want to do with those values where mask is 0 ? Leave them unchanged?

Comment: I edited my questions.
@TheMinion yes, leave them unchanged.
It would be even better if I could do a vertical vector and it deletes the value instead of setting it 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
A =  [8 1 6;3 5 7;4 9 2];
mask = [0 0 0;1 0 1;0 0 1];

%// To know your elements of A greater than the desired value
A_indexes = A > threshold;

%// To get the mask values (note: if your mask is always 
%// binary, this step is not needed) 
mask_indexes = mask == 1;

%// The elements you want to modify
indexes = A_indexes & mask_indexes;

%// Finally the modification
A(indexes) = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the solution is very simple:

```
A = magic(3); %//Example matrix
mask = A<4;   %//Example mask
A(mask)=[];   %//Element removal. Risky if reshape is required later!
%// or A(mask)=0;
%// or A(mask)=NaN;
```

**Edit**:  This solution answers a slightly modified question as clarified by the OP in the comments.

Comment: Shame on me. I have tried every complicate solution, but this was easy. Thanks. But is it also possible to delete instead of setting it 0?
Edit1: Thank you, but I mean a complete delete, so my matrix becomes smaller. I guess I have to reshape() it but I don't know how I can delete it.

Comment: You can't just reshape it because you don't know how many elements get deleted this way.... This is why `NaN` may be useful..

Comment: Since I need it as vertical vector, there is no problem with reshaping the matrices in first place. That's why I hoped, I could delete the the value from my vertical vector shaped matrix.

Comment: Well then, look in my answer - the `A(ind)=[]` command deletes elements.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted your answer.